# How do I remove the first half of a string?

Tags: python

I am trying to remove the first half of a string and just print the second half. The string isn't a constant number of characters so I can't just remove the first a certain number of characters.

```
d = input ("LIST3>")

v = (d[:])
```

This is all I have so far but I don't know how to modify d.

Comment: What if the length is odd number? Do you want the middle character to be included or not?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
v=d[len(d)//2:]
```

Examples:

```
d='abcd'
#v--> 'cd'

d='abcde'
#v--> 'cde'
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for the first half:

```
string[0:int(len(string)/2)]
```

Edit: I just noticed you want to print the second half. Hence:

```
string[int(len(string)/2):]
```

Comment: That would remove the second half, not the first.

Comment: I noticed and corrected the answer